# SQlite3 Join and multiple ordering

Tags: sql, sqlite

SQLite3 - SQL Query
This exercise makes me crazy: what is the query to reach the "First result"?
Is it also possible to reach the "Desidered Result" by using SQL?

table1:

```
+------+----------+------+----------+
| ID1  |   Money  | asd  |  stuff   |
+------+----------+------+----------+
| 8515 | 100      | 777  |     10   |
| 2343 | 500      | data |      5   |
| 2113 | 500      | data |      0   |
| 2342 | 300      | wer  |    55215 |
| 1342 | 100      | wer  |    55215 |
| 1742 | 100      | wer  |       5  |
+------+----------+------+----------+
```

table2:

```
+------+------------+--------+-----------+
| ID2  | anothercol | stuff2 | moneybank |
+------+------------+--------+-----------+
| 8515 | whatever   | 555    | 200       |
| 2343 | cols       | 1300   | 330       |
| 2113 | cols       |  300   | 730       |
+------+------------+--------+-----------+
```

First result*:

```
+------+----------+----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| ID1  |   Money  |  stuff   | stuff2     | moneybank | anothercol|
+------+----------+----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| 8515 | 100      |     10   | 555        | 200       | whatever  |
| 2343 | 500      |      5   | 1300       | 330       | cols      |
| 2113 | 500      |      0   |  300       | 730       | cols      |
| 2342 | 300      |    55215 | null       | null      | null      |
| 1342 | 100      |    55215 | null       | null      | null      |
| 1742 | 100      |       5  | null       | null      | null      |
+------+----------+----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

*Is that a Join between the two table where ID1=ID2?!

Desidered result**:

```
+------+----------+----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| ID1  |   Money  |  stuff   | stuff2     | moneybank | anothercol|
+------+----------+----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| 2113 | 500      |      0   |  300       | 730       | cols      |
| 2343 | 500      |      5   | 1300       | 330       | cols      |
| 8515 | 100      |     10   | 555        | 200       | whatever  |
| 1742 | 100      |      5   | null       | null      | null      |
| 1342 | 100      |    55215 | null       | null      | null      |
| 2342 | 300      |    55215 | null       | null      | null      |
+------+----------+----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

**order by ascending firstly the (stuff and (stuff+ stuff2)) and also moneybank or Money if(moneybank == null)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result joining (outer join) `ID1` with `ID2`. It's not clear from your explanation, but seems a direct result.

The query can look like:

```
select
  a.id1,
  a.money,
  a.stuff,
  b.stuff2,
  b.moneybank,
  b.anothercol
from table1 a
left join table2 b on b. id2 = a.id1
```

The second result is identical to the first one, except for the rows ordering. One way of getting that specific ordering is to sort by `stuff2` and `ID1`. For example:

```
select
  a.id1,
  a.money,
  a.stuff,
  b.stuff2,
  b.moneybank,
  b.anothercol
from table1 a
left join table2 b on b. id2 = a.id1
order by case when b.stuff2 is not null then 1 else 2 end, a.id1
```